# Send mail from Windows SMTP server to Windows POP3 Service on the same machine

Tags: smtp, windows-server-2003, pop3

I've setup a Windows SMTP server and a Windows POP3 service on Windows Server 2003.  Can I have the SMTP server send directly to the POP3 service without setting up a public IP address and domain?  The Windows Server is a VM in it's own Workgroup (no other computers) sitting on top of a corporate network.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the loopback ip address (127.0.0.1) for this, or if you must use a host name then the one mapped to it in the `hosts` file - `localhost`.

Comment: I can send fine, but I need a mechanism to receive.

Comment: Either way, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Micah - using localhost means you do not have to setup a pulibc IP and domain and will allow sending from SMTP to POP3 on the same box.